# Display Ansible configuration from command line

Tags: ansible

Ansible has a pretty long list of configuration parameters including different settings for ssh. Assuming I have some `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` and also other `ansible.cfg` files in current folder, how do I see the resulting configuration?

I am speaking about something like:

```
ansible show-config
ansible-playbook show config
```

Comment: Under what circumstances would you want to have more than a single ansible.cfg?  or is there really just the global environment and your local project cfg?

Comment: Let's say, I just want to be sure that ansible-playbook runs with correct parameters, like see if ControlMaster is really enabled, if pipelining is used and so on, so just see what are the configuration parameters in runtime

Answer (score 5):

Run 'ansible --version'.

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.0.1.0
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = Default w/o overrides

$ touch ~/.ansible.cfg
ansible 2.0.1.0
config file = /home/jdoe/.ansible.cfg
configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

Answer (score 4):

In Ansible 2+ you can easily find this out by running `ansible --version`.

In Ansible 1.X you had to just follow the precedence in the search path for the config iteratively to find out which was being used. The [Ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html) state that Ansible pulls config in the following order of preference:

1. `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` (an environment variable)
2. `ansible.cfg` (in the current directory)
3. `.ansible.cfg` (in the home directory)
4. `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

And prior 1.5 the order was:

1. `ansible.cfg` (in the current directory)
2. `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` (an environment variable)
3. `.ansible.cfg` (in the home directory)
4. `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

It also states that it doesn't merge these at all so you don't have to consider what happens if you have an option in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` but not set in any of the preferential files.

I don't know of a way of asking Ansible directly to show that config it will use if you run Ansible from that directory but you can see it by using this simple bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if ! [[ -z $ANSIBLE_CONFIG ]]; then
  echo $ANSIBLE_CONFIG
  exit 0
elif [[ -f ansible.cfg ]]; then
  cat ansible.cfg
  exit 0
elif [[ -f ~/.ansible.cfg ]]; then
  cat ~/.ansible.cfg
  exit 0
elif [[ -f /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg ]]; then
  cat /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  exit 0
else
  echo "No Ansible config found! Using default settings"
  exit 1
fi
```

I put this in `/usr/local/bin/` (making it executable) and named it `get_ansible_cfg.sh`.

To show it in action we need to set up all of the 4 places Ansible gets config from and then remove them one by one. The values I set up as a test can be seen here:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ echo $ANSIBLE_CONFIG
Set in env variables

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo find / -name "*ansible.cfg"
/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
/home/vagrant/.ansible.cfg
/home/vagrant/inventory/ansible.cfg

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ cat /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
Config in /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/inventory$ cat ~/.ansible.cfg
Set in ~/.ansible.cfg
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/inventory$ pwd
/home/vagrant/inventory
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/inventory$ cat ansible.cfg
Set in local directory ansible.cfg
```

With all of these set and run we get:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/inventory$ get_ansible_cfg.sh
Set in env variables
```

Which returns our `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` test value.

Unsetting this and running again gives us:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/inventory$ unset ANSIBLE_CONFIG
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/inventory$ get_ansible_cfg.sh
Set in local directory ansible.cfg
```

Which is the `ansible.cfg` in the directory that the shell is currently at .

Removing this file then gives us:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/inventory$ rm ansible.cfg
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/inventory$ get_ansible_cfg.sh
Set in ~/.ansible.cfg
```

Which is the test value set in the `.ansible.cfg` file in the current user's home directory.

Finally, removing this gives us:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/inventory$ get_ansible_cfg.sh
Config in /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
```

And if there's no config in any of these locations we get:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/inventory$ sudo rm /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/inventory$ get_ansible_cfg.sh
No Ansible config found! Using default settings
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [ansible 2.4](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/c77e3a74dd17eae757ea61c6bf740d791f790e8b/CHANGELOG.md#24-dancing-days---active-development), there's an [ansible-config](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ansible-config.html) command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

### How to see the active config file?

Two ways :

1. `ansible --version | grep "config file"`
2. Use "-v" with ansible command `ansible all --list-hosts -v”`

### What's the order of precedence?

1) $ANSIBLE_CONFIG (exported env var) --- Highest priority

2) $PWD/ansible.cfg

3) ~/.ansible.cfg

4) /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg  -- Lowest