# SSH Authenticity issue when using Ansible as Terraform provisioner

Tags: ansible, terraform

I am trying to use an Ansible playbook as provisioner for my Terraform project, but I get a SSH authenticity message and it hangs forever.

> The authenticity of host 'xxxx' can't be established.
> ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxxx.
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?

I turned it off on my *ansible.cfg* file, but it doesn't seem to help.

```
host_key_checking = False
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Mind that it should be in the `[defaults]` section of the cfg file. Is it in your case?

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you!

Comment: Which config file is that in? Ansible uses different config files and if you are using one that is dependent on the path then that may impact that. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32414285/2291321 for a further discussion about how Ansible loads config from different files. You can also check with `ansible --version` in the directory you are running Terraform from to see if it is using the expected config version or `ansible-config dump` to see the config settings used.